# Can't print array read from txt file

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, compiler-errors

trying to read from a text file, create an array from the data then print the array. The text file looks like this

GameSave
4
7583
2946
2946
0586

The code should in theory look for the text "GameSave" then read the next line for the array size then the following lines are the array data. It compiles and there are no errors when i run the code but it prints nothing to the screen. Any help would be great.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LoadArray 
{
public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
String fileName = "saveGame.txt";
Scanner kb = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
String gameSave = "GameSave";
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String in = input.readLine().trim();
String length = input.readLine().trim();
int[][] array = new int[Integer.parseInt(length)][Integer.parseInt(length)];
if (in == gameSave)
{
  in = input.readLine();
  String[] temp = in.split("");

  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < array.length; p++)
      {
      array[i][p] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
      System.out.print(array[i][p]);
      }
    System.out.println();
  in = input.readLine();
  temp = in.split("");
}
}



}}
```

Comment: `array = new int[temp.length];` creates a **one-dimensional** array.

Comment: `array[i][p]` you are trying to access from the array as if it was two-dimensional, whereas it's only 1D.

Comment: And not just that, also some logic error in `new int[temp.length];`, it should be `int[Integer.parseInt(temp[0])][Integer.parseInt(temp[1])]` BUT IT'S UGLY, Just save the temp values in another `int` variable first. Also your `split` you're providing an empty String delimiter. How will the method split it?

Comment: Thanks. Missed that.

Comment: @Rob what i understood, i have posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what is expected

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "d:\\saveGame.txt";
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        String gameSave = "GameSave";
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String in = input.readLine();
        String[] temp;
        int[] array = new int[0];
        if (in.contains(gameSave)) {
            temp = in.split(" ");
            array = new int[temp.length - 1];
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 1 ; i < temp.length ; i++) {
                array[j] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
                j++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
            System.out.print("\n" + array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
7583
2946
2946
586
```

Comment: Yes, kind off. This is actually only part of a larger program. I need to create the 2d array for later use. The text file is created from another class that saves the 2d array and this class is for loading or re-creating it. Thanks for the help aswell :)